# Why did my username suddenly add @dhcp?

Tags: users, prompt

I  think my computer might have been hacked. I connected to a University network at BCIT and then my username suddenly shows this.

[systemadmin@dhcp-142-232-165-128 ~]$

All I did is setup Wifi and install Fedora 25 updates. Why did it happen??

Security: WPA & WPA2 enterprise

Authentication: Protected EAP

No CA Certificate

Automatic PEAP Version

MSChapV2 Authentication

Add: Here is my Linux history, I didn't install anything bad.

https://pastebin.com/tzvXATXp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your username hasn't changed. What you are seeing is the two components of your prompt string:

- `systemadmin` - your username
- `dhcp-142-2320165-128` - which appears to be the machine name, probably allocated dynamically by the WiFi router.

They are separated by the `@` - again, nothing to worry about.

Comment: [Related AU answer here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/292269/175072) Also, the hostname could still be static, and the `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND` variables (inefficiently) customised to reverse network IPs for the prompt.

Comment: True, but then the `dhcp` bit would be unlikely to be present.

Comment: Sure it would. It's entirely possible the reverse DNS for the entire DCHP'ed IP range is dynamically allocated as dhcp-<number>-<number>-<number> where those three numbers have a significance for the network topology that lets the sysadmin track down *where* a given system that might be causing trouble is calling in from.

Comment: Yes, but you said reverse network IPs for the prompt, so I assumed that would be from getting an actual IP and locally turning it into the prompt. That wouldn't generate the `dhcp` part.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to a network, and you use dhcp, as is the most used norm in wifi networks (and wired networks), the name of the computer (its hostname) on the network may (and is usually) assigned via that dhcp set up.

You can get your hostname from your DHCP server - it is part of the DHCP specification.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1533#section-3.14

*"This option specifies the name of the client"*

If it was acepted by your computer (as it should), then this should print it:

```
$ hostname
```